# Gmail Auto Forwarding

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Essentially all I want to do is to forward an email from Gmail to another account but when I do Gmail inserts into the new message the original senders details and the email message at the top but I don't want that to appear in the forwarded email.

I know I can manually delete that information but I want this to be an automated process and wondered if there was a script that I could run that would strip out these details before the email was forwarded to the new email address(es)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

That information only appears when you forward an email manually. Using Gmail’s automatic forwarding feature will pass on your email “as-is” (plus a few headers that people won’t normally see). This statement should hold true for all email providers who offer automatic forwarding.

To set this up, click the gear icon, then go to `Settings` → `Forwarding and POP/IMAP`. Click `Add a forwarding address`, and setup your target address.

You will be sent a confirmation code at that address to verify that you own it. Once that is done, you can select your recipient address as shown here:
[image: Gmail Auto-Forwarding]

If you need to only forward specific email messages, you can setup filters instead. You will still need to `Add a forwarding address`, while keeping `Disable forwarding` checked. Then head to `Filters and Blocked Addresses` to `Create a new filter`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I understand what you’re trying to do: you want to keep using Gmail, but every time you want to forward a single email, you would like for all that extra content to be removed. I’m afraid that is not possible from the Gmail web interface.

Many third-party clients have a `Resend` action (in OS X Mail, it’s called `Send Again`) that will achieve what you’re looking for, and it works on emails received as well as ones that you sent. They will make it appear as though you are the person who sent the email to begin with.

[image: Resend in OS X Mail]

Comment: Thank you phong, do you know of any clients that work for Windows PCs?

Comment: Microsoft Outlook had it for the longest time. The last version I used was 2013. I believe you had to double-click the message to open it in its own window, then drop down the same menu that had Reply, Reply All and Forward. I’m not sure if this worked on emails received as well as sent. You could also check out Thunderbird since it’s a very popular client.

Comment: Thanks again phong but do you know if the process could be automated as I really need this to be a fully automated process. Email received gets auto forwarded and blind copied to other people looking as if it came from my email address?

Comment: Isn’t that what my first answer addresses? I’m really confused.

Answer (score 0):

[Mail Forwarder for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-forwarder/hcfnnagnpmdbaddchgpiojjknjlkeigf) is a Google add-on that can forward emails without including the message header. (Disclaimer: I am the writer of the Gmail add-on)

Comment: Please declare your affiliation with this extension. See the [help/behavior].